# Create kernel block device to represent a single file

Tags: linux, macos, kernel, freebsd, kernel-extension

I'd like to design a way to override the read, write and map (page-in) methods on a single file without the burden for implementing a whole new filesystem.

Therefore, I investigate the option to use block device. for the example, my device will represent a dynamic library available for loading by other processes.

So far I was able to create the device using the following code (Written in macOS kernel extension but should be compatible to every BSD based OS).

```
static struct cdevsw my_device =
{
    // Implement the methods
    .d_open = my_open,
    .d_close = my_close,
    .d_read = my_read,
    ...
};

int my_major_index = cdevsw_add (-1 /* auto select index */, &my_device);
dev = makedev (my_major_index, 0);
void * device_node = devfs_make_node (dev, 
                                      DEVFS_BLOCK, 
                                      UID_ROOT, 
                                      GID_WHEEL, 
                                      MY_PERMISSION, 
                                      "my_device");
```

And after this instantiation I have mapped device under `/dev/my_device`,

My question is whether I can simply call this device using `dlopen` (meaning `dlopen("/dev/my_device")` or should I first mount this device to HFS+ filesystem, and copy my dylib to this mount point ?

Comment: Did you consider [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)? It probably would make things simpler, but might be OS specific

Comment: FUSE is overkill for my requirements and I don't really need to invent a new filesystem since I want to implement the read/write/mmap from the block device level. thus, I prefer to create the block device with my own logic, and mount 3rdparty filesystem that on top of it.